# Iframe resizer not working at iphone safari browser

Tags: javascript, html, iframe-resizer

I am using iframe resizer to embed a from from a site to another and this working at all windows and mac, but not at iphone with ios 13. The problem is when I am swithcing froms by clicking next button then the from cutting from top, can you please give a me solution for this?
Here is the form https://mft-haustechnik.de/badsanierung/ under title "Badrechner - Finden Sie heraus was Ihr Bad kostet"